# Proving that a orthogonal vectors form an eigenspace of a symmetric matrix

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, analysis, multivariable-calculus

**Question**

> For $f: \mathbb{R}^n$ \ $\{ 0 \} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ with $f(x) = \frac{x}{|x|}$, we want to show that for each $x$ in the domain $$\Pi^x = \{ w \in \mathbb{R}^n | \space x \cdot w = 0 \}$$ is an eigenspace of the jacboian matrix $\partial f(x)$ and provide the dimension and respective eigenvalue.

**Attempt**

By explicit computation, the Jacobean matrix $\partial f(x)$ is the matrix with $\frac{1}{|x|} - \frac{x_i^2}{|x|^3}$ along the $i^{th}$ diagonal and elements $\frac{-x_ix_j}{|x|^3}$ in all other entries (where $i \neq j).$

As $\partial f(x)$ has $n$ x $n$ entries, it seems very tedious to work out the eigenvalues of a matrix like this, and I was wondering if there is a more simple method to do this.

I would subsequently also be interested in working out the kernel and the rank of $\partial f(x)$, however, as this is an arbitrarily large matrix of functions, this also seems non-trivial to me and I would be grateful for any guidance here as well.

---

**Edit:** Since $\partial f(x)$ is a symmetric matrix we also have that the eigenvalues are all real and that all distinct eigenvectors are orthogonal which should help to simplify calculations slightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $x\in \mathbb R^n\setminus \{0\}$ and let $v\in \Pi^x$. If we think of $x$ and $v$ as column vectors then $$ \partial f(x) = \frac 1 {\vert x\vert }I_n - \frac 1{\vert x\vert^3}xx^T$$ where $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix and $x^T$ Is the transpose of $x$. Hence, \begin{align*}
\partial f(x) v&= \frac  1 {\vert x\vert }v- \frac 1{\vert x\vert^3}(xx^T)v\\
&= \frac  1 {\vert x\vert }v- \frac 1{\vert x\vert^3}x(x \cdot v)\\
&= \frac  1 {\vert x\vert }v .
\end{align*} Here I used that $x^Tv = x \cdot v=0$. Thus, $v$ is an eignevector with eigenvalue $\lambda_x:=1/\vert x \vert $, so $\Pi^x$ is a subset of the eigenspace corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda_x$.

Now you should prove that if $v$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda_x$ then $v\in \Pi^x$, but I believe this should be the same argument as above but in reverse, so I’ll leave for you.

Comment: Is this a different question or are you trying to work out the dimension of the eigenspace? Remember $x$ is fixed, so $\Pi^x$ is just a hyperplane

Comment: No, it would be $n-1$. Think about the case $n=3$. Then hyperplanes are just planes with are $2$ dimensional